# How to get even spacing between TextView in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I got this issue here, which is easily fixed if I would use nested linearlayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView/>
        <TexView/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView/>
        <TexView/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView/>
        <TexView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But is there a way to solve this in constraints layout?
In the image, the square represents a fixed size imageview, the rectangle is a textview which can 1 line (smaller height than imageview) or multiline (height is larger than imageview)

I tried constraints spacing each imageview with xDp, it is ok if ALL textviews are not higher than the imageview, but if a textview is higher than a imageview, it will overlap.
I also tried to do spacing from ImageView to TextView, but then if the TextView is smaller than the ImageView, the spacing will be wrong again.

Is there a way to solve this in ConstraintLayout?

[image]

This is how it looks in Editor
[image]

and its layout xml

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans"
            android:text="This text is a lot longer and overlaps the one below which is bad."
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans"
            android:text="This is a normal length text and that makes it."
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you include your current ConstraintLayout to make it easier for people to provide an answer?

Comment: added a picture

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code of your layout, the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for information i am posting this answer will be useful for future reference
I think that was **ConstarintLayout** problem with **wrap_content** data handling where this is now easy from new **ConstraintLayout** version which is now in **beta**

It introduced new feature  by using this we can tackle this **wrap_content** problem, also @kazhiu's answer will do workaround here because of fixed height of **ImageView** it will not work if ImageView have an wrap_content or dynamic height so in this case **constraint.Barrier** is useful.
 for setup bet ContraintLayout we have to do following

add maven support in project gradle file as below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

then in app gardle dependencies add ConstarintLayout library dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
```

Here is the same @kazhiu's code using constraint.Barrier

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierone"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrierone2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/barrierone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView,textView"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/barrierone2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView2,textView2"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Design and blue print

[image]

in **android.support.constraint.Barrier**

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="id1,id2"
```

will contain the id's of views which are wrap_content on top of other views, also we can create horizontal barrier by replacing height to match_constraint(0dp) and width to wrap_content

Comment: Yes your solution is perfect. My solution is workaround, because I don't use beta version in commercial projects :)

Comment: @kazhiu i know no one goes with Beta for live projects, i noted that is in beta and for future reference nothing other intention :)

Answer (score 1):

I can do that if you will change `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` in your `ImageView` to constant dimensions e.g. `48dp` instead `wrap_content` then in your `TextView` add `android:minHeight="48dp"`. Below adds an working example and xml:

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. "
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```